# break not terminating do-while loop

Tags: c++, do-while

So this is going to be a stupid question but I cannot for the life of me figure this out at the moment... This do-while loop below does not terminate as it should.

```
    do {
            if(inp.eof())
                    throw("Unexpected end of file");

            getline(inp, l);
            line++;

            std::stringstream com(l);

            com >> command;

            if(command == ">>") {
                    std::cout << "Why?" << std::endl;
                    break;
            }
    } while(command != ">>");
```

From this loop, if command were to ever become ">>", it should end one of two ways right? Unfortunately, my code simply outputs the "Why?" inside the if, ignores the break statement entirely, and continues through the loop until eventually I get to inp.eof(), where it throws an error. This should be basic, but somehow, I have no idea what it's doing.

EDIT: Update: When I change it to a while(true) and keep the break statement, it works perfectly. Change it back to a do-while and it fails. Not sure why, but the darn thing works and that's all I care about at the moment.

Comment: Are you sure you have the break in there when it was compiled? In seems crazy that the `Why?` is printed but the break doesn't occur!

Comment: Yep. Absolutely positive. Edit to add: did a "make clean" and a "make all" just to be doubly sure, and sure enough, same thing.

Comment: What type is command?

Comment: does break work if you just put `if(line == 2){ std::cout << "breakTest\n"; break; }`? (Assuming that the line is a count of lines and reaches 2).

Comment: Maybe somethings happened to the comparison operators, try using command.compare(">>") instead

Comment: This is nuts. try changing the position of break or what prints (instead of just `Why?`). Maybe the compiler is doing something crazy?

Comment: @QuentinUK: That's what it was at first, it didn't work.

Comment: @QuentinUK But the OP said that it prints `Why?` which means the compare must be working somewhat. Thats what is making this question so ridiculous.

Comment: FYI - you shouldn't need the `break;` and the `while(condition)`. They're doing the same job in this code sample.

Comment: @tmack: I know, but one of them wasn't working, so I was hoping the other one would.

Comment: @Ben: Changing the position of the break to the beginning of the while statement (instead of the end) causes it to not print anything at all. I moved it back and changed "Why?" to "Why are you doing this to me?", which printed

Comment: I changed the input file so that it contained multiple lines of ">>". My code now outputs "Why are you doing this to me?" several times but still refuses to break

Comment: Previously, in my input file, there is a blank line directly after ">>". When I remove that, the break statement works perfectly. When it is put back, it no longer works again. No idea why a blank line after ">>" would cause this particular error

Comment: What's `inp`? Does it contain the `>>`? I tried your code at [Live Work Space](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1JhVM2$5) and it ran fine without modification. I treated `inp` as an alias for `std::cin`, so my best guess, at present, is that your `inp`, whatever it is, is somehow missing the `>>`.

Comment: `inp` is a `std::ifstream`, which most definitely has a `>>`. I tried this with 3 different compilers (g++, mpicxx, and nvcc) and all produced the same result, so...

Comment: Would you post a [short, self contained, compilable, example](http://sscce.org/) along with sample input that reproduces the problem?

Comment: You should probably be doing `if(!inp)` instead of `if(inp.eof())`.

Comment: Don't hate me for asking this, but are you invoking this loop from another loop?

Comment: Show us your entire program, please! :)